# How do I ask a question where I want to know what a certain set of code does?

Tags: discussion

I don't know how to ask this.

http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/injection-of-ejbs/README.html

I want to know how this is dependency injection because it doesn't look like I thought it would.  How can I ask, hey, how does this code show DI?  That's not a good question, is it for SO?

How would I word a question like this so I don't get downvoted?

I wasn't even sure what tag to use for Meta.  And, I'm not asking for the answer here, just how to ask it there.

Thanks.

Comment: You will have to present some specific questions instead of a general "is this X". *Why* don't you think it is DI? Can you back this up with external resources?

This might be more suited for Programmers.se though.

Answer (score 1):

"What does this code do" is not a good question.

Post your actual question on Programmers.  Describe in detail why you think it's not Dependency Injection, and why it doesn't have the same benefits as DI, perhaps comparing it to an orthodox DI example.

Make your question interesting enough to the experts to get them to consider it thoughtfully.  If your only premise is that you believe they're using the wrong vocabulary at the page you linked, that might not qualify as interesting.

Try to tie it to the relative merits of DI, rather than a vocabulary lesson.  Don't merely make it *"This isn't DI, amirite?"*